# How to get the actual data from a response? I get undefined

Tags: javascript, http, fetch

I am trying to get data from the yelp api,

I have a fetching function that looks like this:

```
export function fetchRestaurants (term) {
    const endpoint = `businesses/search?term=${term}&location=NYC`

    return fetch(endpoint, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+'oSJvaTmFtYVCEJcMsLFA4uRljDOILtEfp0sTWflSWclozapMP1rCZ6uttKPOoYnrdUGcTXI0ztOf3rTPVSBRa1JjngqcoTKD30YUp7yKxhZCNzS4bsZV_DqzzkAwXXYx',
      }), 
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        res.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        // this is undefined!
        return data
      })
  }
```

the respose is `200` on the first `then` and looks like this:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/businesses/search?term=pizza&location=NYC", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/businesses/search?term=pizza&location=NYC"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
```

But then i try to do a `.json` on it on the second `then`, and when i try to log it  its undefined.

Any ideas on how to get the actual data? 
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @HereticMonkey — No, because the question says that `data` is undefined in the second `then()` callback.

Comment: check for errors before returning res.json()

Comment: @EugenSunic — They **aren't** returning `res.json()`, that is the error.

Comment: @Quentin Even if they return `res.json()`, the return value of `fetchRestaurants` will still be `undefined` and the duplicate will apply.

Comment: @HereticMonkey — But they aren't asking about that

Comment: @Quentin Just trying to save the OP some time.

Comment: @Quentin you obviously missed what I said, I said in addition to the non-returning promise check for errors also... throw if exist if not then ()=>res.json()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `.then` callback function needs to **return** the `res.json()`
Like this:

```
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res.json()
  })
```

Comment: no because the second one which is called `data` in my example is undefined.. so i cant call .json on undefined.

Comment: @giorgiomartini — `data` is undefined in the second `then` **because** you didn't return anything from the first `then` (which this answer tells you to correct).

Comment: That's because you didn't return anything in the previous callback in the promise chain...

Comment: @silencedogood if you edit your answer to say that i needed to return the value on the FIRST then ill accept it,, thx

Comment: @giorgiomartini — It has `res.json` in it. The first one has `res.json` in it. The second one doesn't. It **shows** that it is talking about the first `then` already.